How to download in action Resource route remix?
I have follow the guide from remix-run but fail to generate a download file.
I have checked guide from both stackoverflow :
Remix: file download
How to return a plain text or css file from remix route?
AND remix repo
https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/5533
Here is the sample code for replicate the issue
import { Form } from '@remix-run/react';
export const action = loder () => {

  const content = 'some text content...';
  console.log('test load')
  return new Response(content, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'plain/text',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="some.txt"',
    },
  });
}
export const action = async () => {

  const content = 'some text content...';
  console.log('test action')
  return new Response(content, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'plain/text',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="some.txt"',
    },
  });
}

export default function Index() {
    return (
      <>
        <Form action="/app/test" method='post'>
            <input name="id" value="1" />
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </Form>
        <Link to="app/test" reloadDocument>Download</ink>
      </>
    )
}

This generate a normal API return instead of Resource Route
Note: This is a page from Shopify App Remix Boilerplate source code

Since you have a UI component in your route, this is not a resource route, so loaders and actions can only return JSON.
If you want to return a file, you should POST to a separate resource route:
// routes/some-ui-route.tsx
import { Form } from '@remix-run/react';

// this is your UI component
export default function Index() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* POST to your resource route */}
        <Form action="/upload" method='post'>
            <input name="id" value="1" />
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </Form>
        <Link to="app/test" reloadDocument>Download</ink>
      </>
    )
}

// routes/upload.ts
export const action = () => {
  const content = 'some text content...';
  console.log('test load')
  return new Response(content, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'plain/text',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="some.txt"',
    },
  });
}


